# MongoDb $near - How to retrive items with nearest location from an array

Tags: mongoose

I have a Mongo Database that has the following structure

```
**Coupons Schema**
--coupon 1  
---by merchant 1  

**Merchants Schema**  
--merchant 1  
---merchant locations  
----[lat,long]  
----[lat,long]  
----[lat,long]
```

The above structure tries to illustrate that a coupon belongs to a merchant and the merchant can have multiple locations.

I am looking for a way to select all the coupons that are closest to the user given the user's [lat,long].

Answer (score 0):

I ended up merging coupons into the merchants Schema. According to advice from other stack overflow answers, Mongo is relational and therefore Join statements or hacks are not encouraged.

From that I was able to use [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) to derive the distance.